# Retangle beside text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the following using html and css.

[image I am trying to create - click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orQLv.png)

I would like it to be responsive, but I do not know where to begin. Please help.

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried so we may assist.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-left

Comment: HTML<div class='box'>
  <p>WHO WE SERVE</p>
</div>

Comment: .box {
  border-left: 4px solid #750808;
  height: 40  px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box p {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left:10px;
}

Comment: No, please edit your question with your code -- don't post it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

simple

```css
.desire{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Arial";
  letter-spacing: -0.5;
  padding-left: 7px;
  color: #414141;
  border-left: 4px solid #840000;
}
/*example*/
.a{
  font-size: .7em;
}
.b{
  font-size: 1.7em;
}
.c{
  font-size: 2.7em;
}
```

```html
<p class="desire a">WHO WE SERVE</p>
<p class="desire b">WHO WE SERVE</p>
<p class="desire c">WHO WE SERVE</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What would it be if you wanted the text to be centered?

Comment: put `text-align: center;`